# Passing data to a deep ancestor widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have eight screens. The first 7 screen has data to be sent to the last screen how do I go arouund this??

I tried passinng it through from one parent to another but that is too much work

Comment: create a provider/class or static variable or use shared preferences or what ever you like !!!!

Comment: You can also use GetX state management. You can create a main controller class to hold the values and later in your last screen just call the controller and all your data will be in that controller.

Answer (score 4):

why don't you use a state management like `provider`???
if you don't use a state management it'll be hard to use datas from one screen to another step by step.
you can create a class like this:

```
class ExpampleClass extends ChangeNotifier {

String? _yourData;

void setYourData(String? newData){
_yourData = newData;
 notifyListeners();
}

String? get yourData => _yourData;

}
```

as you see when `_yourData` is changed, it tells you and you can use this data where ever you want by providing `ExpampleClass`,even you can set a data in your first screen and use that data in the last screen without passing data step page by step.

```
Provider.of<ExpampleClass>(context, listen: false).yourData;
```

and even you can use that data in your widgets like this by using `Consumer` everywhere you want:

```
Consumer<ExpampleClass>(
        builder: (context, exampleClassProvider ,snapshot) {
          return Text(exampleClassProvider!.yourData);
        }
      )
```

***be careful to use MultiProvider in your first root class of your project to define your providers.

here is [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) document. read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

you need an global state solution, like provider, riverpod, getx etc …
there’s good book on this in amazon "Managing State in Flutter Pragmatically”